# Calculating hamming distance by appending '0' to lesser length string

Tags: c, string

I have to find the hamming distance between two codes.

For example if I input:

> a= 10
>
> b= 1010

Automatically a should be made equal to the length of the string b by appending 0's.

So the input should become:

> a=0010
>
> b=1010

But I'm getting instead:

> a = 001010
>
> b = 1010

Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
void main()
{
    char a[20],b[20],len1,len2,i,diff,count=0,j;
    printf("Enter the first binary string\n");
    scanf("%s",a);
    printf("Enter the second binary string\n");
    scanf("%s",b);

    len1 = strlen(a);
    len2 = strlen(b);

    if(len1>len2)
    {
        diff = len1-len2;

        for(i=0;i<len1;i++)
        {
            b[i+diff]=b[i];
        }

        j=i+diff;
        b[j]='\0';

        for(i=0;i<diff;i++)
        {
            b[i]='0';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        diff = len2-len1;

        for(i=0;i<len2;i++)
        {
            a[i+diff]=a[i];
        }

        j=i+diff;
        a[j]='\0';

        for(i=0;i<diff;i++)
        {
            a[i]='0';
        }
    }

    printf("\nCodes are\n");
    printf("a=%s\n",a);
    printf("\nb=%s\n",b);

    for(i=0;a[i]!='\0';i++)
    {
        if(a[i]!=b[i])
        {
            count++;
        }
    }

    printf("hammung distance between two code word is %d\n",count);
}
```

Can anyone help me to fix this issue?

Comment: Try to indent your code so it is easier to read for the possible answerers.

Comment: `void main()` is wrong! See [What should main() return in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c)

Comment: You should be specifying maximum widths to avoid buffer overflows, e.g., `scanf("%19s",a);`.

Comment: @InternetAussie: it isn't wrong, it's only meaningless.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte-- [`void main()` _is_ wrong for portable C, according to the Standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.2.1p1). Other signatures are implementation dependent.

Comment: Thank you all issue is closed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your two `for` loop where you are moving the content of your old tab to the right to insert the zeros, you inverted the lengths.

First loop should be:

```
for(i=0;i<len2;i++)
{
    b[i+diff]=b[i];
}
```

And second:

```
for(i=0;i<len1;i++)
{
    a[i+diff]=a[i];
}
```

After trying it:

> Codes are
>
> a=0010
>
> b=1010
>
> hammung distance between two code word is 1

Also, the main function should return an `int`, not `void`. As stated in the comments, you should also change the type of your `len1`, `len2`, `i`, `diff`, `count` and `j` because you use them as number values, not as characters. You can for instance either use the `int` or `size_t` types for that.

```
int main()
{
    char a[20],b[20];
    int len1, len2, i, diff, count=0, j;
    // Rest of your code
}
```

Comment: Also, all of the variables `len1`, `len2`, `i`, `diff`, `count`, and `j` should be of type `size_t`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method that does not prepend zeros to the shortest binary string, and avoids the limitations of `strtol()` by comparing the elements of the string directly, starting with the last characters. The intricacies of using `strtol()` are traded for more complexity in handling the array indices. Note that care must be taken to avoid counting down to a negative value since `size_t` types are used. This method is not limited by the capacity of `long` types, but rather by `size_t`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char a[20], b[20];
    printf("Enter first binary string: ");
    scanf("%19s", a);
    printf("Enter second binary string: ");
    scanf("%19s", b);

    size_t a_len = strlen(a);
    size_t b_len = strlen(b);
    size_t max_len = a_len > b_len ? a_len : b_len;

    size_t hamming_dist = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < max_len; i++) {
        if (a_len - i > 0 && b_len - i > 0) {
            if (a[a_len - i - 1] == b[b_len - i - 1]) {
                continue;
            }
        }
        if ((a_len - i > 0 && a[a_len - i - 1] == '1') ||
            (b_len - i > 0 && b[b_len - i - 1] == '1')) {
            ++hamming_dist;
        }
    }

    printf("bstring_1: %s\n", a);
    printf("bstring_2: %s\n", b);
    printf("Hamming distance: %zu\n", hamming_dist);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And he even speaks proper English (*prepend* verses *append* `:)`

Answer (score 0):

A way that doesn't need to pad one of the parameters with zeroes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()
{
    char *a = "1010";
    char *b = "10";

    long unsigned int xorab;
    unsigned int hammingDistance = 0;

    xorab = strtoul(a, NULL, 2) ^ strtoul(b, NULL, 2);

    while (xorab) {
        hammingDistance += xorab & 1;
        xorab >>= 1;
    }

    printf("%u\n", hammingDistance);   
}
```

It uses `strtoul` to convert the binary strings to `unsigned long int` using a base 2, then you only have to use bitwise operators (xor, and, shift) to calculate the Hamming distance without to take care of the size difference.

Obviously, this way stops to work if you want to test binary strings with values greater than an unsigned long int.